# How to create scrollable codeblock inside the table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is there some good way to have scrollable code block inside HTML table cell?

Here is the markup to test it:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1em;
}

pre {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p>Outside of the tables, code works correctly:</p>

<pre>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</pre>

<p>And here is a table:</p>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <pre>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</pre>
      </td>
      <td>
        <pre>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</pre>
      </td>
      <td>
        <pre>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <pre>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</pre>
      </td>
      <td>
        <pre>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</pre>
      </td>
      <td>
        <pre>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you see, the table extends the screen width, and it is bad.

Is there a to have table width 100% of the screen, columns of equal width, and scrollable code blocks inside these columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a width te table and reset the table-layout

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout
>
> The `table-layout` CSS property sets the algorithm used to lay out `<table>` cells, rows, and columns.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1em;
}

pre {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: pre;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<p>Outside of the tables, code works correctly:</p>

<pre>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</pre>

<p>And here is a table:</p>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <pre>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</pre>
      </td>
      <td>
        <pre>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</pre>
      </td>
      <td>
        <pre>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <pre>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</pre>
      </td>
      <td>
        <pre>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</pre>
      </td>
      <td>
        <pre>A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Great, thanks. (Well, it doesn't really solve my particular case: I need it for Asciidoctor tables. Fixed layout breaks things. But in normal HTML it works, and therefore the answer is upvoted/accepted, of course).

Comment: @johnc.j. you may set a max-width to the pre element if that helps :)